# Implementing BackgroundWorker's RunWorkerCompleted using Tasks

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, backgroundworker, task

I have a WPF MVVM application.  In one of the ViewModels, I have the following:

```
this.GoCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
{
    var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                this.Progress = i + 1;
                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
        }).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                // should act like RunWorkerCompleted
                this.DoSecondTask();
            },
            scheduler
        );
});

private void DoSecondTask()
{ 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                // repeated task for simplicity
                this.Progress = i + 1;
                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
        }).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                this.Status = "Done.";
            }
        );
}
```

When I click the button bound to the GoCommand, I see the progress bar move from 1-100.  When the ContinueWith executes `DoSecondTask`, though, that task runs in the UI thread.  How can I change the `DoSecondTask` function to run the second `for` loop in a new thread (or outside of the UI thread)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367895/net-why-does-threading-task-task-still-block-my-ui/4040332#4040332) answer.  It's interesting to note that this **does not** work:

```
private void DoSecondTask()
{ 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(_ =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                // repeated task for simplicity
                this.Progress = i + 1;
                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
        }, TaskScheduler.Default).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                this.Status = "Done.";
            }
        );
}
```

But this **does**:

```
private void DoSecondTask()
{ 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                // repeated task for simplicity
                this.Progress = i + 1;
                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                this.Status = "Done.";
            }
        );
}
```